# Update @Updatetimestamp without changeing data of entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

A ChildEntity has a many-to-one relation to a ParentEntity

The ParentEntity, has a:

```
@Version
@UpdateTimestamp
protected LocalDateTime modificationTime;
```

The requirement is that modificationTime of ParentEntity Row must be updated, when a ChildEntity is created or modified (in a @Transactional context) by `ChildRepository extends JPARepository`

The only way we currently see, is to create a method `updateModificationTime` and set it explicitly, wondering if there is a better way?

How can we update the @UpdateTimestamp annotated modificationTime without changeing any data of the ParentEntity?

github repo:
https://github.com/daveyx/spring-playground/tree/main/210427-datatest

testcase:
https://github.com/daveyx/spring-playground/blob/main/210427-datatest/src/test/java/com/example/datatest/child/ChildServiceIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Did you try annotating the entity with `@DynamicUpdate` yet?

Comment: thanks, tried `@DynamicUpdate` without success. Furthermore we don't like the downsides of this annotation

Comment: What do you mean without success? This also requires that saving always goes through the parent and that the child collection cascades `MERGE` and uses `@OptimisticLock`. What kind of downsides?

Comment: no success when just saving the Parent https://github.com/daveyx/spring-playground/blob/main/210427-datatest/src/main/java/com/example/datatest/child/ChildService.java
when saving via parent without changeing data. Saving via Parent also works without `@DynamicUpdate`, but this is not what we want. We want to save the Child and just touch the Parent in order to update the `@UpdateTimestamp` Downside of @DynamicUpdate is that hibernate needs to create the SQL instantly and can not use predefined SQL.

Comment: In that case your only option is to use e.g. `entityManager.lock(parent, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)`

Comment: `@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
@Query("SELECT pe FROM ParentEntity pe WHERE pe.id = :parentId")
ParentEntity findByIdForceIncrement(@Param("parentId") Long parentEntityId);`
in `ParentRepository extends JpaRepository` works and looks best for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Chris, `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` seems to be a "correct" way for us.
Getting the parent entity within the transactional context, updates the `@UpdateTimestamp` annotated property:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<ParentEntity, Long> {

@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
@Query("SELECT pe FROM ParentEntity pe WHERE pe.id = :parentId")
ParentEntity findByIdForceIncrement(@Param("parentId") Long parentEntityId);
```